# Mobile Azure Service C# .NET Backend PATCH not updating

Tags: c#, .net, azure, mobile, patch

I've created a simple .NET backend mobile azure service in C#.  I have the mobile service up and running (all it's doing currently is working with your normal CRUD on a single table).  The problem I'm having is that the PATCH/UPDATE will not do as it says.  I can do everything else I've tried, SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, but I've been unable to update data.

When I debug into the block of code that calls UpdateAsync, the patch.GetEntity()..... always has the values NULL or zeroed out or day one datetimes, like it's not passing along the property values of what I'm trying to update.  The only value I ever have is the correct id.  Below I tried to strip out some of the code I have, I used some of what was in the first few tutorials on the Azure website.

I have a Data Object:

```
public class AdminLookupDATA: EntityData
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int lookuptype { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime editdate { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DTO:

```
public class AdminLookupDTO
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int lookuptype { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime editdate { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Model:

```
public class AdminLookupModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int lookuptype { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime editdate { get; set; }
}
```

My PATCH inside my controller:

```
    public Task<AdminLookupDATA> PatchAdminLookupDATA(string id, Delta<AdminLookupDATA> patch)
    {
         return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }
```

Also, I have the same issue if I try to run the PATCH function directly from the browser in the "try it out" section, so it's something I have configured wrong within the service project itself. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Have you used AutoMapper to map your DTO correctly to database object?

Answer (score 0):

Your property names must start with a capital letter.

Otherwise configure the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver as indicated here:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx

code snippet

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Comment: don't post only `link` if the `link` is broken then ur answer is useless

Comment: I have this same issue, but GlobalConfiguration doesn't seem to be a class in my azure mobile service project.